# tar-file repository error with jackrabbit oak

Tags: java, guava, jackrabbit-oak

i am working since a few months with jackrabbit oak. While everything works fine with MongoDB as backend, i got problems by using a tar file based Segment NodeStore.

Here, working just with nt:folder nodes works like with MongoDB, but when i try to handle files (nt:file) i get following error massage (when writing nodes to repository):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.equal(Lcom/google/common/io/InputSupplier;Lcom/google/common/io/InputSupplier;)Z
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.memory.AbstractBlob.equal(AbstractBlob.java:68)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentBlob.equals(SegmentBlob.java:217)
at com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(Objects.java:60)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.memory.AbstractPropertyState.equal(AbstractPropertyState.java:53)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.memory.AbstractPropertyState.equals(AbstractPropertyState.java:90)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:748)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:726)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:726)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:726)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:726)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter$ChildNodeCollectorDiff.childNodeChanged(SegmentWriter.java:877)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.memory.ModifiedNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(ModifiedNodeState.java:416)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter$ChildNodeCollectorDiff.diff(SegmentWriter.java:892)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeNode(SegmentWriter.java:714)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeBuilder.getNodeState(SegmentNodeBuilder.java:111)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore.rebase(SegmentNodeStore.java:269)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.rebase(MutableRoot.java:223)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.refresh(SessionDelegate.java:506)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.prePerform(SessionDelegate.java:611)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:205)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:112)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.internalSetProperty(NodeImpl.java:1363)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:506)
at org.opencms.file.OnOffRepoCustomUnique.putResource(OnOffRepoCustomUnique.java:1229)
at org.opencms.file.OnOffRepoTest.testVersioning(OnOffRepoTest.java:873)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

it seems to be a problem with guava.. Is this a bug in oak or it is my fault? But where could the problem be?

Comment: Multiple / invalid versions of Guava in your classpath? What does `mvn dependency:tree` output regarding Guava?

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. The problem came from a postgres dependency, because postgres integrated a further guava dependency. Removing postgres solved it (it was just included because of testing and was not needed anymore)

Comment: can i mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have multiple / invalid versions of Guava in your classpath. Please check what does `mvn dependency:tree` print regarding Guava.